# Unix Awk group by

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Can anyone shed me light how to group by based on the username and sum the values divide it by number of rows of that specific username. for example below.

```
root 25 oracle 25  batch 30  griduser 20 admin 35

root 55 oracle 45 batch 30  griduser 10

oracle 35 batch 30  griduser 30 xuser 45 admin 85
```

---

My output should be as follows.

```
root 40 oracle 35 batch 30 griduser 20 xuser 45 admin 60
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: homework problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the output order:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2){a[$i]+=$(i+1);b[$i]+=1}}
    END {
        for(i in a){
            printf "%s %d ",i,a[i]/b[i]
        }
        printf "\n"
    }' file
oracle 35 griduser 20 admin 60 root 40 xuser 45 batch 30
```